# Interactive, real-time bikeshare web application with Bokeh

Tags: python, beginner, python-2.x, unit-testing

As a side project, I'm working on a Bokeh web application to display public bikeshare data on a map. The data is updated every 2 minutes using a periodic callback. Below is the full implementation. I'm using PyBikes (https://github.com/eskerda/pybikes) to scrape the bike data. I'm interested in feedback on the use of good coding style/best practices. Also, I'm trying to learn about unit testing but I'm unsure what kind of unit tests would be appropriate here. Any other comments on how this code could be improved are welcome as well.

````
import json
import math
import pybikes

from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.tile_providers import get_provider, Vendors
from bokeh.models import GeoJSONDataSource, ColorBar, LinearColorMapper, Label
from bokeh.palettes import viridis


def latlon_to_mercator(lat, lon):
    """Converts latitude/longitude coordinates from decimal degrees to web mercator format.

    Derived from the Java version shown here: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mercator

    Args:
        lat: latitude in decimal degrees format.
        lon: longitude in decimal degrees format.

    Returns:
        Latitude (y) and longitude (x) as floats.
    """

    radius = 6378137.0
    x = math.radians(lon) * radius
    y = math.log(math.tan(math.radians(lat) / 2.0 + math.pi / 4.0)) * radius

    return y, x


def color(percent_full):
    """Returns a color from the Viridis256 palette corresponding to how full a station is.

    Args:
        percent_full: A value between 0-1 indicating percent full status of a station

    Returns:
        Color from the Viridis256 palette as a hex code string

    """
    idx = int(percent_full*255)
    colors = viridis(256)
    color = colors[idx]

    return color


def gbfs_to_geojson(stations):
    """Converts General Bikeshare Feed Specification (GBFS) data to GeoJSON format.

    Args:
        stations: A list of GbfsStation objects.

    Returns:
        A json string containing GeoJSON-formatted data for each station
    """
    geo_dict = {}
    geo_dict['type'] = 'FeatureCollection'
    geo_dict['features'] = []
    for station in stations:
        station_dict = {}
        station.latitude, station.longitude = latlon_to_mercator(station.latitude, station.longitude)
        if station.bikes == 0 and station.free == 0:
            percent_full = 0
        else:
            percent_full = float(station.bikes)/float(station.bikes + station.free)
        station_dict['geometry'] = {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [station.longitude, station.latitude]}
        station_dict['type'] = 'Feature'
        station_dict['id'] = station.extra['uid']
        station_dict['properties'] = {'station name': station.name,
                                      'bikes': station.bikes,
                                      'free': station.free,
                                      'color': color(percent_full),
                                      'size': (station.free + station.bikes)*0.5}
        geo_dict['features'].append(station_dict)
        geo_json = json.dumps(geo_dict)

    return geo_json


def get_data():
    """Pulls bikeshare data from the web using the Pybikes API.

    Returns:
        A json string containing GeoJSON-formatted data for each station
    """
    capital = pybikes.get('capital-bikeshare')
    capital.update()
    stations = capital.stations
    geo_data = gbfs_to_geojson(stations)

    return geo_data


def make_map(source):
    """Creates a Bokeh figure displaying the source data on a map

    Args:
        source: A GeoJSONDataSource object containing bike data

    Returns: A Bokeh figure with a map displaying the data
    """
    tile_provider = get_provider(Vendors.STAMEN_TERRAIN_RETINA)

    TOOLTIPS = [
        ('bikes available', '@bikes'),
    ]

    p = figure(x_range=(-8596413.91, -8558195.48), y_range=(4724114.13, 4696902.60),
               x_axis_type="mercator", y_axis_type="mercator", width=1200, height=700, tooltips=TOOLTIPS)
    p.add_tile(tile_provider)
    p.xaxis.visible = False
    p.yaxis.visible = False

    p.circle(x='x', y='y', size='size', color='color', alpha=0.7, source=source)

    color_bar_palette = viridis(256)
    color_mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette=color_bar_palette, low=0, high=100)
    color_bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=color_mapper, background_fill_alpha=0.7, title='% Full',
                         title_text_align='left', title_standoff=10)
    p.add_layout(color_bar)

    label = Label(x=820, y=665, x_units='screen', y_units='screen',
                  text='Dot size represents total docks in station', render_mode='css',
                  border_line_color=None, background_fill_color='white', background_fill_alpha=0.7)
    p.add_layout(label)

    return p


def update():
    geo_json = get_data()
    source.update(geojson=geo_json)


source = get_data()
source = GeoJSONDataSource(geojson=source)
fig = make_map(source)
curdoc().add_root(column(fig))
curdoc().add_periodic_callback(update, 120000)
```
````